# What is "full clutching flow" in fluid-dynamics with regards venturi design?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex, design, potential-flow

As the title says, what is *"full clutching flow"* in fluid-dynamics with regards venturi design?

I came across this reference a few times and can not find any further info on it, I'm currently designing a venturi for a product and this question has lingered for a while. Thanks for any help you can be!!

Comment: Could you provide a reference in which you found it?

Comment: A quick google search turns up... only this question. Without a reference, we can't really help.

Comment: I've never heard of this either.  I'm guessing that it refers to choked flow. Did this only come up in the context of gasses at high flow rates?  second (less likely): something to do with separated flow in the diffuser